# Can a curve of constant width have a straight side?

Tags: geometry

It seems that the curves of constant width that I've seen are all "curves" in the sense that any support line only cut through one point. I just wonder if it could have a straight side?

Answer (score 2):

Assume there is such a curve of constant width $d$. Let it "stand" on a straight edge $AB$ and let $P$ be a highest point in that orientation. Then $P$ is $d$ above the base line. But one of $A$, $B$ is further than $d$ away from $P$.